# How can I get DoubleTwist to differentiate between music and podcasts?

Tags: itunes, music, podcasts, data-synchronization

Since iTunes has no way to sync with my Motorola Droid, and all of my music is on my Macbook Pro, I recently tried out DoubleTwist.  It detected my Droid right away.

The problem is that when I chose to sync all of my music, DoubleTwist also synced all of my podcasts, which quickly filled up my sd card with stuff I don't want on there.  Is there a way to have it only sync my iTunes music library and ignore podcasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the screenshots, doubleTwist allows syncing specific playlists *and* has smart playlists.

Create a smart playlist that would contain all your library but not podcasts (excluding genre Podcast), and sync it.

Comment: I'm not able to find an option for creating a 'smart' playlist.  I'm assuming this would be what I would need as it would automatically include newly added music, but the file menu only allows creation of 'dumb' playlists.

Comment: well they added smart playlists, but this app is such a steaming pile of crap that it's not worth going through the trouble.  Not sure why they had to make a whole app for what I can already do directly on my phone (download apps, purchase amazon mp3's), or in finder (copy music to my sd card).